# How to format the file path in an MLTable for Azure Machine Learning uploaded during a pipeline job?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, automl, azureml-python-sdk, azure-ml-pipelines

> How is the path to a (.csv) file to be expressed in a MLTable file
> that is created in a local folder but then uploaded as part of a
> pipline job?

I'm following the Jupyter notebook *automl-forecasting-task-energy-demand-advance* from the *azuerml-examples* repo ([article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-auto-train) and [notebook](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/jobs/automl-standalone-jobs/automl-forecasting-task-energy-demand/automl-forecasting-task-energy-demand-advanced.ipynb)). This example has a MLTable file as below referencing a .csv file with a relative path. Then in the pipeline the MLTable is uploaded to be accessible to a remote compute (a few things are omitted for brevity)

```py
my_training_data_input = Input(
    type=AssetTypes.MLTABLE, path="./data/training-mltable-folder"
)

compute = AmlCompute(
        name=compute_name, size="STANDARD_D2_V2", min_instances=0, max_instances=4
    )

forecasting_job = automl.forecasting(
    compute=compute_name, # name of the compute target we created above
    # name="dpv2-forecasting-job-02",
    experiment_name=exp_name,
    training_data=my_training_data_input,
    # validation_data = my_validation_data_input,
    target_column_name="demand",
    primary_metric="NormalizedRootMeanSquaredError",
    n_cross_validations="auto",
    enable_model_explainability=True,
    tags={"my_custom_tag": "My custom value"},
)

returned_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
    forecasting_job
)

ml_client.jobs.stream(returned_job.name)
```

> But running this gives the error

Error meassage:
Encountered user error while fetching data from Dataset. Error: UserErrorException:
Message: MLTable yaml schema is invalid:
Error Code: Validation
Validation Error Code: Invalid MLTable
Validation Target: MLTableToDataflow
Error Message: Failed to convert a MLTable to dataflow
uri path is not a valid datastore uri path
| session_id=857bd9a1-097b-4df6-aa1c-8871f89580d8
InnerException None
ErrorResponse
{
"error": {
"code": "UserError",
"message": "MLTable yaml schema is invalid: \nError Code: Validation\nValidation Error Code: Invalid MLTable\nValidation Target: MLTableToDataflow\nError Message: Failed to convert a MLTable to dataflow\nuri path is not a valid datastore uri path\n| session_id=857bd9a1-097b-4df6-aa1c-8871f89580d8"
}
}

```yaml
paths:
  - file: ./nyc_energy_training_clean.csv
transformations:
  - read_delimited:
        delimiter: ','
        encoding: 'ascii'
  - convert_column_types:
      - columns: demand
        column_type: float
      - columns: precip
        column_type: float
      - columns: temp
        column_type: float
```

> How am I supposed to run this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For Remote PATH you can use the below and here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-data-assets?tabs=Python-SDK) for create data assets.

It's important to note that the path specified in the MLTable file must be a valid path in the cloud, not just a valid path on your local machine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But how is the workflow supposed to be? Working from a local Jupyter notebook, you define the MLTable locally _and thus the path to the data_; then this MLTable along with the data is uploaded when you run `ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(my-automl-job)`. But now this path to the data (in the MLTable file) should point to its location in a Datastore, which doesn't exist when you define the file? How am I supposed to do this?